# Devolver Error en Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

El caso lo tengo en un programa muy sencillo con Windows Forms programando en C# lo que pasa es que cuando dejo espacio en blanco en alguno de los textbox o ingreso un caracter no valido el programa truena y regresa al codigo con:
System.FormatException: 'La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.'
Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando se ingrese un dato no valido en el textbox o haya un null , devuelva un mensaje de error y no que el programa truene completamente
no se como pudiera hacerle, les dejo el codigo

```
    using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.ComponentModel;
   using System.Data;
   using System.Drawing;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.Windows.Forms;

   namespace Tarea1_2
   {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BtnRes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double masa, volumen,resultado;
            masa = Convert.ToDouble(txtMasa.Text);
            volumen = Convert.ToDouble(txtVol.Text);
            resultado = masa / volumen;
            lblRes.Text = ("El Resultado es: " + resultado);

          }
     }
   }
```

Comment: Investiga sobre try catch y sobre double.TryParse

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar esta problema, tiene que hacer validacion de los inputs en txtMasa y txtVol.

Un metodo es utilizar el function [Double.TryParse](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8).

Asi, puede modificar el codigo como asi:

```
private void BtnRes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double masa, volumen, resultado;

    /*
       Si TryParse returns TRUE, significa que: txtMasa tiene el formato correcto, 
       la conversion a double tiene exito,
       y el valor es asignado al variable "masa"

       Si TryParse returns FALSE, presenta un MessageBox
     */
    if (!Double.TryParse(txtMasa.Text, out masa))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Masa no tiene el formato correcto");
    }


    /*
     * Repite el metodo para txtVol
     */
    if (!Double.TryParse(txtVol.Text, out volumen))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Volumen no tiene el formato correcto");
    }


    // Si quiere comprobar los valores de masa y volumen ahora
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("masa = {0} & volumen = {1}",masa.ToString(), volumen.ToString()));


    resultado = masa / volumen;
    lblRes.Text = ("El Resultado es: " + resultado);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe un bloque para controlar errores.

```
try
{
 //Aca va tu codigo
}
catch(exception ex)
{
 //Aca entra si y solo si algo del codigo del bloque try no funciona.
 //mostrando un MessageBox con la información de porque el error sin hacer que el programa se finalice.
 MessageBox.Show(ex.message);
}
```

Ahora, si lo que queres es controlar los errores que estas seguro que puedan suceder como espacios en blanco y demás podrías hacer esto en el evento `KeyPress` del control `Textbox`

```
 private void textbox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
         if (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        else if (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        else if (Char.IsSeparator(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else if (char.IsPunctuation(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }            
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Esto sirve para controlar mediante el `KeyPressEventArgs` que tipo de carácter se esta ingresando y si no es el que podemos convertir mediante tu función que no haga nada, básicamente no escribe si pone caracteres que no necesitamos.

A su vez podrías incluir un try...catch dentro de esa función porque al permitir caracteres de puntuación estos `#$%^&*(..etc` son permitidos y podrían hacer que el programa devuelva una excepción no controlada.

Answer (score -1):

Para lo que estas haciendo lo mejor es que utilices validadores del lado del cliente, WebForms tiene ya incorporados los mismos, pero por lo que veo estas aun aprendiendo, por lo que esta bien que agregues la validacion en tu logica

Lo que debes hacer primero de todo es no utilizar Convert, sino el metodo TryParse que tiene tipo de dato y ademas verificar si el valor del campo de texto es vacio  null

Puedes utilizar este codigo

```
Double masa;
Double volumen;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMasa.Text) && Double.TryParse(txtMasa.Text, out masa))
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtVol.Text) && Double.TryParse(txtVol.Text, out volumen))
        {
            if (volumen > 0)
            {
                resultado = masa / volumen;
                lblRes.Text = ("El Resultado es: " + resultado);
            }
            else
            {
                lblRes.Text = ("Error en Volumen");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblRes.Text = ("Error en Volumen");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lblRes.Text = ("Error en masa");
    }
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos!

Comment: Es un programa de escritorio. no hay cliente ni servidor aca.

Comment: Pero el concepto es el mismo, en Winforms tb tienes herramientas para realizar la validación de los campos de un formulario (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/user-input-validation-in-windows-forms)